# Проверка данных в конструкторе

Tags: java, валидация

Доброго дня, уважаемые java-гуру
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как более правильно работать с констуктором объекта, когда нужно делать проверку данных?
Делать ли проверку в самом конструкторе и выбрасывать исключение, если пришли неправильные данные. Или же нужно сделать отдельную функцию, которая сначала будет проверять данные на валидность и только потом вызывать конструктор для этих данных?

Answer (score 4):

Если вы передаёте в конструктор один-два параметра, а проверки на валидность не содержат сложной логики, то есть смысл оставить валидацию внутри конструктора. Если логика проверки сложная, есть смысл вынести её в отдельный класс. Если в конструктор передаётся много параметорв, многие из которых необходимо валидировать, есть смысл реализовать шаблон "[Строитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)" и осуществлять проверки в нём.